# scrlttr2 location positioning question

Tags: letters, lengths, scrlttr2

I would like to have the text of the variable `location` to be right aligned with the text of the main body. So I tried to redefine the length `lochpos` to be the same as `refhpos`, because the margin on the left is the same as on the right, but it doesn't work.
Any idea where I make a mistake?

The pseudo lengths could be found [here, p. 354](http://ftp.fau.de/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf)

MWE:

```
    \documentclass[foldmarks=true,foldmarks=blmtP,
    version=last]{scrlttr2}
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
    \usepackage{graphics}
    \usepackage{lipsum}

    \makeatletter
    \@setplength{lochpos}{\useplength{refhpos}} 
    \makeatother

    \begin{document}
    \setkomavar{location}{\raggedleft
    Text should be right aligned to the main body text!}
    \begin{letter}{%
    Joana Public\\
    Hillside 1\\
    12345 Public-City%
    }
    \opening{Dear ...,}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \closing{Regards}

    \end{letter}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Do i remember correctly, that you have to define the pseudolengths in an external file and load them (for example as a global option?).

Comment: @Johannes_B Yes, when I understand it correctly the pseudolengths are for developers and can be defined in .lco files. But I think the `\makeatletter` `\makeatother` should also work. A quick test revealed that it makes no difference if I define it in a .lco file or in the main file.

Comment: Up to using geometry? Since the `textwidth` is dependant of the DIV-Value, the h-offset needs to be calculated summing up `marginparwidth`, `marginparcolsep` ...

Comment: @Johannes_B Wouldn't it be enoght to subtract from `paperwidth` the `textwidth` and the left margin width to get the width of the right margin which should be the correct value for `lochpos`? But that seems not to work either. I've seen the Komaold letteroption which aligns the text of the `location` variable correct, but it's an old style which also makes many changes I don't want to have. Could you maybe extend your answer as I don't know how to start now.

Comment: Aha, well, may I ask which papersize you have choosen for your tex distribution (letter or DIN A4). For me it is A4 (used in Germany). Add `\usepackage{showframe}` to display the used frame ... Then you can see the needed number. May I ask why you want to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The right lenght seems to be `\oddsidemargin+1in`.

So you should add

```
\makeatletter
  \@setplength{lochpos}{\oddsidemargin}
  \@addtoplength{lochpos}{1in}
\makeatother
```

MWE (added `geometry` to show the frame)

```
\documentclass[foldmarks=true,foldmarks=blmtP,
version=last]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} % just to show the frame

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
  \@setplength{lochpos}{\oddsidemargin}
  \@addtoplength{lochpos}{1in}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\setkomavar{location}{\raggedleft
Text should be right aligned to the main body text!}
\begin{letter}{%
Joana Public\\
Hillside 1\\
12345 Public-City%
}
\opening{Dear ...,}
\lipsum[1-2]
\closing{Regards}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I would never had found the information in the documentation on page 331.

Comment: @user2653422 You're welcome.