# Enlarge location in scrlttr2

Tags: horizontal-alignment, koma-script, scrlttr2

I read this question [scrlttr2 location positioning question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220770/scrlttr2-location-positioning-question) and now have a follow up question.

How do I enlarge the location in KOMA-Script class `scrlttr2`? My added line (the one with the comment) is only a work around, but doesn't enlarge the box (?), so the warnings keep staying.

```
\documentclass[foldmarks=true,foldmarks=blmtP,
version=last]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} % just to show the frame

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
  \@setplength{lochpos}{\oddsidemargin}
  \@addtoplength{lochpos}{1in}
  \@addtoplength{lochpos}{24pt}%only moves the location, but doesn't enlange it
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\setkomavar{location}{\raggedleft
verylongline12345678901234}
\begin{letter}{%
Joana Public\\
Hillside 1\\
12345 Public-City%
}
\opening{Dear ...,}
\lipsum[1-2]
\closing{Regards}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To enlarge the in KOMA-Script, class `scrlttr2` called location you need to add the line

```
  \@addtoplength{locwidth}{6cm} % enlarges location <===================
```

to your code. Change the value `6cm` for your needs.

To give you a better overview I deleted in the following MWE your used `geometry` line (because it changes the layout of the letter, better use package `showframe`) and added the following three lines

```
\LoadLetterOption{visualize} % <========================================
\showfields{address,location,refline} % <===============================
\usepackage{showframe} % just to show the frame <=======================
```

Now you can see the location visualized with a black frame.

With the following MWE

```
\documentclass[%
  foldmarks=true, foldmarks=blmtP,
  version=last
]{scrlttr2}

\LoadLetterOption{visualize} % <========================================
\showfields{address,location,refline} % <===============================
\usepackage{showframe} % just to show the frame <=======================

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
  \@setplength{lochpos}{\oddsidemargin}
  \@addtoplength{lochpos}{1in}
  \@addtoplength{locwidth}{6cm} % enlarges location <===================
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\setkomavar{location}{\raggedleft
verylongline12345678901234}
\begin{letter}{%
Joana Public\\
Hillside 1\\
12345 Public-City%
}
\opening{Dear ...,}
\lipsum[1-2]
\closing{Regards}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

you get the wanted result:

[image]

With KOMA-Script version 3.26 or later you can use command `\addtoplength` instead `\@addtoplength` etc. To make sure that your cade can only be compiled with the correct version or later versions add `[2019/02/01 v3.26b]` to `scrlttr2`:

```
\documentclass[%
  foldmarks=true, foldmarks=blmtP,
  version=last
]{scrlttr2}[2019/02/01 v3.26b] % <============== compiles only with version v3.26b or more

\LoadLetterOption{visualize} % <========================================
\showfields{address,location,refline} % <===============================
\usepackage{showframe} % just to show the frame <=======================

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% no @ needed with version KOMA-Script 3.26 <===========================
\setplength{lochpos}{\oddsidemargin} % <================================
\addtoplength{lochpos}{1in} % <=========================================
\addtoplength{locwidth}{6cm} % enlarges location <======================


\begin{document}
\setkomavar{location}{\raggedleft
verylongline12345678901234}
\begin{letter}{%
Joana Public\\
Hillside 1\\
12345 Public-City%
}
\opening{Dear ...,}
\lipsum[1-2]
\closing{Regards}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

with the shown result above!